# sendTransaction sometime not landing on the blockchain

Tags: web3.js, send-transaction, raydium

I'm currently using the *solana/web3.js* and *raydium-sdk* library to perform swap with tokens. Everything seems to be working fine, however, I after sending my transaction with the *sendTransaction* function:

```
  async sendVersionedTransaction(tx: VersionedTransaction) {
    const txid = await this.connection.sendTransaction(tx, {
      skipPreflight: true,
    });

    return txid;
  }
```

I often have a transaction with no data like this: https://solscan.io/tx/5tRonjzQzaxB67Hr4ZpYEQbiK9Uzfcjir66cC4tbACoeU6yBoenb1wDHdDepU5GpQ6cBKCHkJUrCCiHRxUG1D7aq

I can't tell when or why it is happening since it can be random at times. Anybody knows why ?

Answer (score 2):

The transaction you sent [was dropped](https://explorer.solana.com/tx/5tRonjzQzaxB67Hr4ZpYEQbiK9Uzfcjir66cC4tbACoeU6yBoenb1wDHdDepU5GpQ6cBKCHkJUrCCiHRxUG1D7aq), likely because it did not have enough priority fees to be included in the block.

To add priority fees to your transaction, you can follow [the priority fee guide](https://solana.com/developers/guides/advanced/how-to-use-priority-fees) which showcases the compute budget instructions:

```
const modifyComputeUnits = ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitLimit({
  units: 300,
});

const addPriorityFee = ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitPrice({
  microLamports: 20000,
});

const transaction = new Transaction()
  .add(modifyComputeUnits)
  .add(addPriorityFee)
  .add(
    SystemProgram.transfer({
      fromPubkey: payer.publicKey,
      toPubkey: toAccount,
      lamports: 10000000,
    }),
  );
```

**Note**: You may need to add more compute units depending on your transaction. It is recommended to figure out how many you need to avoid overpaying for your transaction.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I have try this but i still dont have a satisfying result. My transaction is still often dropped. I used helius API to estimate the priorityFee: https://docs.helius.dev/solana-rpc-nodes/alpha-priority-fee-api, with a **High** priorityFee,and then made a swap with raydium-sdk function: https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk-V1-demo/blob/abe9cb685f1f3c169ad59c1974bf86e2a7064337/src/swapOnlyAmm.ts#L61 I added  `      computeBudgetConfig: {
        microLamports: maxLamports,
      }` , in the makeSwapInstructionSimple method for the priorityFees